# How to install Ubuntu LTS (18.04) on a system for which disk drivers are existing only i the most recent, non-LTS version?

Tags: 18.04, kernel, 19.10, live-cd, downgrade

I am holding in my hands a cool ASUS UX481F (ZenBook Duo) that works surprisingly well out-of-the-box (including network and disk) with Ubuntu 19.10 live USB, but the Ubuntu 18.04 both liveUSB and MinimalDisk is too old to recognize the disks.

Do I have any options to install Ubuntu 18.04 on it anyway?

I can see two theoretical solutions:

1. Include a newer kernel (e.g. using HWE or  UKUU) in the installer (if that is possible). If I had an option, I would prefer to use the Ubuntu 18.04 MinimalCD image rather than standard liveCD.
2. Downgrade Ubuntu 19.10 back to 19.04 - I've seen the instructions on the blog: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-downgrade-ubuntu-linux-system-to-its-previous-version .

The questions:

1. **Which option is preferable?**
2. **How do I upgrade the kernel in the (minimal) liveCD image**
3. **Did anyone succeeded in downgrading vanilla Ubuntu 19.10 to 18.04?**

Comment: You didn't mention which 18.04 you tried; ie. original 18.04, 18.04.2 (with 18.10 HWE software stack), 18.04.3 with 19.04 software stack, or 18.04.4 (19.10's stack though it's still in QA-testing currently).

Comment: `apt` and like tools make upgrading to later packages real easy; downgrading to older is manual, possible but a lot more work.  Because 19.10 appeared to work for you, I'd just use 18.04.4 as I've noted no issues with it in testing (*noting of course my hardware is different, my usage very different etc*)

Comment: @guiverc I didn't know the 18.04.4 comes with 19.10 HWE. But of course I tried the very latest 18.04 - standard installer, server installer and obviously the minimallCD. All three could not find my hard disk.

Comment: It's best if you are specific, rather than use terms like the 'latest'.  Did you try 18.04.4?  as given what you said, it's what I would have tried.  If you did, what 'date' was it?  Standard installer again is vague; `ubiquity` is standard for desktop, but you can also use `subiquity`, `di`.... depending on what image you selected. ie. being specific can help.

Comment: Good point, thank you. In fact, I've tried 18.04.3. How do I get 18.04.4? It is not released yet, isn't it?

Comment: http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/384/builds   ps: if you have trouble installing with that, please file a bug & record it on iso.qa.ubuntu.com (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) ; it'll help get it fixed for 18.04.4 before release.  *Thanks in advance for taking the time to report this bug and helping to make Ubuntu better*.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you! I will try that!

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the link to the daily builds, I was having trouble finding that

Answer (score 0):

@guiverc comment was right on spot: when I used the Ubuntu 18.04.**04** from the http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/bionic/daily/20200112/bionic-server-amd64.iso (it is a text-mode installer, very much the same as the MinimalCD) I had no problems in recognition of the disk and network hardware.

You make the USB key with in the same way as any other LiveCD image - by blindly writing it over the whole USB disk. I prefer using `ddrescue` over `dd` because it gives visual feedback and gives an option to resume the process.

```
wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/bionic/daily/20200112/bionic-server-amd64.iso
lsblk # and find out which drive is usb. Let's assume it is /dev/sdc
sudo apt install gddrescue
sudo ddrescue --force bionic-server-amd64.iso /dev/sdc /tmp/resume.log #The last command is for resume and is optional. --force is to overwrite any pre-existing partitions on the USBdrive.
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading Ubuntu 19.10 -> 18.04 also worked for me. This is the path I took:

1. Install the Ubuntu 19.10 using the standard installer
2. Log into it with virtual console (i.e. switch to the text mode with Ctr+Alt+F2)
3. Make sure you have network connection.
4. `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop`
5. `sudo apt autoremove`
6. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
7. `sudo apt install aptitude` - aptitude is better at resolving potential package conflicts then apt.
8. Patch the sources by replacing the 19.10 codename (eoan) with bionic:

`sudo sed -i 's/eoan/bionic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

8. As sudo make a file `/etc/apt/preferences` with the following content:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=bionic
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

9. `sudo apt update` - make sure it runs successfully.
10. `sudo apt upgrade`
11. `sudo apt dist-upgrade` If you see problems in downgrading any of the packages (i.e. errors, not warnings) try to "upgrade" (i.e. effectively downgrade) the package with aptitude by `sudo aptitude upgrade <package_name>`.
12. `sudo apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04` this step is very important. We don't want to be left without the new kernel
13. `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` - or whatever other state you want to be left with. For instance, I actually rather use [i3wm](https://i3wm.org/) rather than gnome, so instead I install just graphical desktop manager (aka login manager) `sudo apt install gdm3` and follow the installation procedure for i3.

All credits go to the author of https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-downgrade-ubuntu-linux-system-to-its-previous-version